# How to use boto3's export_image?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, boto

It seems like the EC2 client is missing the `export_image` function, even though its [listed in the EC2 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=export#EC2.Client.export_image).

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=my_aws_profile)
client = session.client('ec2')
client.export_image()  # MISSING!
```

```
AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'export_image'
```

Am I missing something? (other than the function's parameters?)

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code? Because the code is correct.

Comment: Yes. It’s correct.

Comment: So the code is definitely correct. Maybe you have some very old version of boto3 or you somehow overwritten it?

Comment: Seems likely. Will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
>>> ec2.export_image()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 677, in _make_api_call
    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 725, in _convert_to_request_dict
    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 293, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "DiskImageFormat"
Missing required parameter in input: "ImageId"
Missing required parameter in input: "S3ExportLocation"
>>> boto3.__version__
'1.17.76'
```

Comment: An older version of boto3 was my problem.